# Apps like Firefox or VLC won't open and just show black screen

Tags: amd-graphics, wayland, tearing

I am using a clean install of Ubuntu 22.10. This problem only happens while using Wayland. It looks like screen tearing. My mouse glitches in the screen and some parts of the screen don't change for a few seconds. [image: Example image] When it happens apps like Firefox or VLC won't open and shows a black screen. I researched it a bit but couldn't find a solution. It's really frustrating because it happens quite often. I am using an AMD card with out-of-the-box drivers.

I don't want to open a duplicate bug report but I couldn't find a similar one either. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: What is the model of the video card and the drivers being used?

Comment: It's an old laptop with HD 4650m. Tbh it works quite well with an SSD. This is the only problem I'm facing. I am not sure how can i find my driver info.

Comment: This will guide you through finding out what GPU is in the machine. https://itsfoss.com/check-graphics-card-linux/#:~:text=Use%20lspci%20command%20to%20find,sound%2C%20network%20and%20graphics%20cards.

Comment: BTW changed your title to the actual question.

Comment: 01.00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Sony Corporation RV730/M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165]
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

Comment: Should i share lshw -C video as well?

Comment: OK so this is the GPU you have Radeon HD 4650/5165. Next you need to find if there is an actual driver for this GPU and install it. It seems the kernel driver is not quite right for it.

Comment: I see. So how can i find the right drivers and install them?

Comment: You can start with a Google search for the driver.

Comment: https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/ati-radeon-hd-4000-series/ati-radeon-hd-4650   I found this but it doesn't say it supports wayland. Is it okay to install?

Comment: Does it say the driver is for Ubuntu 22.10?

Comment: Nah, it just says Display Drivers for Xorg 6.9 to Xserver 1.12 and Kernel version up to 3.4. I switched to Xorg to tinstall it now. When I run the .app file as a program it asks for my password, checks integrity than a red line appears and immediately it closes.

Comment: That will not work you are using a 5.15 kernel if using the default kernel. This must be an extremely old GPU and may not have a driver that will work with a modern OS.

Comment: The Radeon HD 4650 was a graphics card by ATI, launched on September 10th, 2008 Very old.

Comment: Yeah, guess we won't be able to fix it. Thx for your help regardless David.

Comment: Maybe try a version of Ubuntu that does not need as much of a computer to run. Try Lubuntu.